# Namespace resolution with operator== in the STL

Tags: c++, stl, namespaces, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider a simple type, in a namespace, with an `operator==`:

```cpp
namespace ANamespace {
    struct Foo { int i; float f; };
}

#ifdef INSIDE

namespace ANamespace {
    bool operator==(const Foo& l, const Foo& r)
    {
        return l.i == r.i && l.f == r.f;
    }
}

#else

bool operator==(const ANamespace::Foo& l, const ANamespace::Foo& r)
{
    return l.i == r.i && l.f == r.f;
}

#endif

bool compareElements(const std::vector<ANamespace::Foo>& l, const std::vector<ANamespace::Foo>& r)
{
    return l == r;
}
```

If `operator==` is defined inside `ANamespace` (by defining `INSIDE`), the example compiles. But if `operator==` is defined in the global namespace (the `#else` case), the function `compareElements()` doesn't compile - both in GCC and Clang, and with both libstdc++ and libc++.  All emit a template error along the lines of:

```
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/vector:60:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:820:22: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const ANamespace::Foo' and 'const ANamespace::Foo')
            if (!(*__first1 == *__first2))
                  ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~
...
```

However, directly comparing two `Foo`s in a function, e.g.,

```
bool compareDirectly(const ANamespace::Foo& l, const ANamespace::Foo& r)
{
    return l == r;
}
```

seems to work fine regardless of where `operator==` is defined.

Are there rules in the standard about where the STL expects `operator==` to be defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!(*__first1 == *__first2)` takes place in `std::operator==`, a function template, so it is considered a dependent unqualified function call expression, so during overload resolution only functions found within the definition context of `std::operator==` and those found via ADL are candidates.

Clearly there are no `operator==(const Foo&, const Foo&)` declared within the context of the definition of the standard comparison operator. In an argument dependent lookup (ADL) the namespaces of each of the arguments are checked to search for a viable function for the call, so this is why defining `operator==` inside of `ANamespace` works.

Answer (score 2):

In short, declaring `operator==` in the same namespace in which your class is declared guarantees that argument-dependent lookup will find it, so that's what you should do. The standard does not mandate that you follow this convention, but in practice it is the only way to obtain the guarantee. This also applies to other operators that the standard library might invoke on your types.

If you choose to declare `operator==` in the global namespace but your type is *not* declared in the global namespace, there is a chance that the standard library algorithm will still be able to find your `operator==` through unqualified name lookup. However, there's no guarantee that this works, since unqualified name lookup will *stop* at the innermost enclosing namespace in which `operator==` is found. In other words, in an algorithm of the form

```
namespace std {
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2 >
constexpr bool equal( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                      InputIt2 first2 ) {
    // ...
}
}
```

the unqualified name lookup of `operator==` will find any `operator==`s declared in the `std` namespace (which of course, will not be applicable to your user-defined type) and then, if it found anything in `std`, even though it may not be a viable overload, will not look in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on "ADL" aka "Argument Dependent Lookup".

Basically, when you write `v1 == v2`, the compiler looks for an `operator==` taking two arguments of the correct type `ANamespace::Foo` in the current namespace. *(Note: We're ignoring conversions here)*. If it can't find one, then it will look in the namespace that the type is defined in (`ANamespace`).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) has an article about this.

Comment: I assumed that the problem was related to ADL, but this answer doesn't really explained how/why ADL comes into play here.